# Как правильно подключить функции из sqlite3.dll

Tags: c++, winapi

Здравствуйте у проблема с подключением функций из библиотеки sqlite3.dll, я использую LoadLibrary/GetProcAddress, я хочу подключить её динамически но не очень понимаю какой тип переменных мне нужно задавать при присваивании им функции. Вообще это для меня какой-то тёмный лес, и я был-бы очень благодарен если вы продемонстрируете подключение одной функции `мне больше и не надо :)` например sqlite3_open

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что библиотеки обычно подключают не так? Или это в образовательных целях?

Comment: Используйте [доки](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya) -- там написаны возвращаемые типы функций

Comment: `decltype(::sqlite3_open) *`